# MySQL Login Error

Tags: login, password, mysql

I recently installed mysql-server on my Ubuntu 14.04 LTS computer and was able to log in only once.

I didn't change any passwords or user information but now when I try and login it keeps throwing

```
ERROR 1045 (28000): Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: YES)
```

I've also tried to sign in with my $USER account, no username etc., but no luck.

To try and fix this I followed this walk-through on how to bypass the need for a password: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/MysqlPasswordReset

This hasn't worked though as it throws the same error but with `(using password: NO)` at the end.

Any ideas on how to proceed?

Thanks,

Eric

Answer (score 0):

Reset your MySQL root password by doing the following:

```
sudo service mysql.server stop
```

then start mysql skipping table granting

```
sudo mysqld --skip-grant-tables &
```

Login to MySQL as root

```
mysql -u root mysql
```

Change your root password

```
UPDATE user SET Password=PASSWORD('new-password') WHERE User='root'; FLUSH PRIVILEGES; exit;
```

Restart mysql

```
sudo service mysql.server restart
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but these steps are almost identical to the ones in the link I posted and result is the same. I get the Access Denied error.